# alert() function is looping when called in focus() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, focus, alert

I Want an Alert pop-up when focusing on input. It pops up correctly but when I click on 'OK' or 'x' i.e cancel, it Loops infinitely and never closes.

```
$('input').focus(function () {
       alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: 1. Control receives focus, alert kicks in, control loses focus.  Alert closes control gets focus.  Go back to 1.

Comment: You could try something like my answer below, temporarily disabling the focus event for the element after the alert, and enabling it again a few milliseconds later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `input` is assuming the focus again when the `alert` is closed (which is the new focus when it appears - notice the outline around the button in the dialogue?)

If you only want to make the alert show once, you could perhaps write something a resembling this:

```
let hasShownAlert = false

$('input').focus(function () {
  if (!hasShownAlert) {
    hasShownAlert = true
    alert('hello')
  }
})
```

Of course you could improve this with state containers or something, but this is the simplest way you could achieve it. (Note: the `hasShownAlert` variable has to be defined outside of the `onfocus` handler, otherwise it'll be cleared up by the garbage collector.)

---

Updated: So if you don't want it to only show once, there are a couple of things you could do. The first, the simpler, would be listening for the `click` event, rather than focus. The second way could be setting a `didShowAlert` variable -- inverting the value each time the handler is fired. E.g...

```
let didShowAlert = false
$('input').on('focus', (ev) => {
   if (didShowAlert) {
     didShowAlert = false
   } else {
     didShowAlert = true
     alert('hello')
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a hack like

```
$(document).on("focus", 'input:not(.unFocus)', function() {
       alert('hello');
       $('input').addClass('unFocus');
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('input').removeClass('unFocus');
       }, 10);
});
```

It may not be the ideal way to do it, but it works :)